# Sending arguments to executables from another program

Tags: c++, command-line, system

I know this can easily be done using the platform's *system()* implementation. However, from what I have read using `system` is often not the best approach and can lead to security drawbacks. Is there a different industry standard approach to this type of problem? What are the options available to the user to do this sort of thing?

I am specifically interested in the implementation in C/C++, but I do not think this type of thing will be language dependent; I suspect it shall be platform specific.

Comment: To clarify, you have a program and from that you want to run another program (like `system` does) but using some other way than the `system` call? Then yes it will be platform dependent. On POSIX platforms (like Linux or OSX) read about the [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) system call and the [`exec` family of functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), on Windows read about [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Correct. I am not against using `system`, I have just read that using this poses security threats. I was just curious to see what alternatives exist. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the standard POSIX functions [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and [`exec*`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html). This works for Unix-like platforms (Linux and Mac).

On Windows, there's the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

`fork` and `exec` are a little odd, because `fork` duplicates your current process entirely and returns different results to each copy. The new copy of the program should then set up any needed settings (closing files that shouldn't be open in both programs, changing environment variables, etc.) and finally call one of the `exec` functions, which replaces that process with the specified program (while maintaining the currently open file descriptors and such).

Answer (score 2):

The security issue which you alluded to with `system` is that `system` uses the system's shell to execute the program and parse its arguments, and if you're not careful, the shell can do things you don't want.  (For example, "ls " + argument seems innocuous, but it can delete data if argument is "; rm -rf /*").

If you control the arguments, or if you're careful to escape any shell metacharacters in your parameters to system, you should be okay, although it's most reliable to avoid it.

To avoid the security issue, use a method of spawning a program that lets you specify a *list* of arguments, already parsed, instead of specifying a string that has to be parsed to extract arguments:

- Using POSIX, [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) then call one of the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) functions.
- On Windows, use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Use a cross-platform library function like the Apache Portable Runtime's [`apr_proc_create`](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__thread__proc.html#gab51dd90b98d365a969f0ec5c7bef4e14).

These don't *exactly* match system()'s behavior (system, for example, does a bit with signal handling and return values), but they're close.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely already seen it's mention, but `fork()` and `exec` are typically the choices to go with in Linux programming, but for Windows, you'd have to use the OS API to create a new process. `system()` is still a good choice for smaller project because they typically don't run into the same malicious problems that big-name software can. It also natively waits for the child application to return before continuing on in the parent program, which can be a nice trait if you're using an external binary to run calculations or something else and you'll be getting the return value.

A lot of people will tell you that using `system()` is wrong, but it's really not. It's frowned upon in the professional market because of its inherent problems, but otherwise it works.

Comment: `system` is really just very limited.

Comment: It is, not to mention the shell commands themselves are platform specific, making its native cross-platform capacity pretty much moot. It can be helpful if you're just trying to get something to work, however, which is important for work flow, but it should be replaced with a more polished example sometime before release.